# How to downgrade server kernel to desktop kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, kernel

Currently I am looking [at this  way](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-use-more-than-3gb-ram-on-32-bit-ubuntu.html) to solve my problem that uses more than 3GB RAM on 32-bit Ubuntu.

For various reasons, I am trying to downgrade server kernel to desktop kernel. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: My English is poor, thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Thanks for you help, I am Xavier Zhao.

My account is already not available, so I use this account to reply.

I will try to solve it tomorrow and give you feedback

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is run the following commands on a terminal and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

That will install the "generic" desktop kernel along with your existing kernel.  It should set the generic kernel as default, but you will be able to select between that and any previous kernels you have installed from the GRUB boot menu.